# How to hide certain simulator items from Xcode 7 destination menu in the toolbar?

Tags: xcode, simulator

I have tried disabling "show in destination menu". But that does not work.
I am trying to hide all version except 8.4 & 9.0 without uninstalling them. How can that be done?

I hope this question is not considered a non-programming question. Because there is no answer anywhere for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also tried hiding certain Simulators that I usually don't build for to help reduce menu clutter. Unchecking the 'show in destination menu' option also did not have any effect.

The best I could do was to just **delete** the Simulator from the Devices window.

I know that if I wanted to re-add that simulator for future testing, all I had to do was tap the '+' icon, and click 'Add Simulator', and add the desired Simulator.

[image]